# NZ Zorro, Ant design nz-table dynamic columns does not align

Tags: angular, html-table, antd, ng-zorro-antd

I have a table where columns are **dynamically** sent by the server. Table headers and the data columns do not align.

How do I make them align?

```
<nz-table *ngIf="queryResults" #headerTable [nzData]="queryResults" [nzFrontPagination]="false"
    [nzShowPagination]="false" [nzScroll]="{ y: '150px' }">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th *ngFor="let c of queryCols">{{c}}</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr *ngFor="let d of headerTable.data">
        <td *ngFor="let c of queryCols">{{ d[c] }}</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </nz-table>
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Need to specify the `nzWidth` for `th` when fixing the header in v8.5.x or old.

We are about to release version 9(stable) and it will adaptive width. now, you can try on https://next.ng.ant.design/components/table/en#components-table-demo-fixed-header